# How to overwrite 'tab' key behaviour to complete input in console?

Tags: c#, console

I am working with an example Calculator project where user can input the option (operation type) he needs to perform in the console. Currently I am matching the complete input provided by user to check if the option he entered exists in my list of options and then perform the operation.
Currently the options list is as below (Will be extended with more new options further on) :

```
List<string> options = new List<string>()
{
   "add",
   "divide",
   "multiply",
   "subtract",
   "modulus"
};
```

User input for specifying the operation :

```
op add
op divide
```

'op' here is a specific start of input that specifies that further keyword will be a operation option.

Currently now I am reading entire line and then splitting the input and deciding whether the syntax for input and option matches my need.

I was thinking is it possible to include behavior to auto complete the option input when user presses tab  key. (Like what happens with intellisense or windows 'cd' command). Currently pressing tab key adds spaces in the input line.

Eg :

```
op mul --> press 'tab' --> op multiply
```

I was trying to read key using `Console.ReadKey()` and see if anything is possible but no luck so far.

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();   //Currently fetching input string using this
//var key = Console.ReadKey();       //Not sure what to do here
//split inpput further and check if it matches correct syntax and option entered
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this is more fiddly than you might think, because you will have to effectively write your own version of `Console.ReadLine()` which will have to handle things like cursor movement, backspace, delete and so on. It would also have to handle expand the current line of text in the console when you press TAB to expand a keyword.

However if you can get away with a cut-down version that only allows backspace you can write something like this (this is just sample code to get you started; a proper solution would require proper error handling):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var lookup = new Dictionary<string, string> // Expandable keywords
            {
                ["mul"] = "multiply ",  // Note trailing spaces. You may not want those.
                ["div"] = "divide " ,
                ["sub"] = "subtract ",
                ["mod"] = "modulus "
                // etc
            };

            while (true)
            {
                string result = ReadLineWithKeywordExpansion(lookup);
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }

        public static string ReadLineWithKeywordExpansion(Dictionary<string, string> lookup)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            string blank = new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth - 1);

            while (true)
            {
                var k = Console.ReadKey();

                if (k.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    return sb.ToString();
                }
                else if (k.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
                {
                    if (sb.Length > 0)
                        --sb.Length;
                }
                else if (k.Key == ConsoleKey.Tab)
                {
                    if (lookup.TryGetValue(lastChars(sb, 3), out var rep))
                    {
                        sb.Length -= 3;
                        sb.Append(rep);
                    }
                }
                else if (k.KeyChar != '\0') // Ignore special keys.
                {
                    sb.Append(k.KeyChar);
                }

                Console.Write("\r" + blank);
                Console.Write("\r" + sb.ToString());
            }
        }
        
        /// <summary>Returns the last 'n' chars of a StringBuilder. </summary>

        static string lastChars(StringBuilder sb, int n)
        {
            n = Math.Min(n, sb.Length);
            char[] chars = new char[n];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                chars[i] = sb[i + sb.Length - n];

            return new string(chars);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that for brevity I've hard-coded the keyword length to 3. You might want a more sophisticated lookup, but the general principles above apply.

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm. I would like to even complete the input if user inputs any length string that matches with options .. eg 'op subt' or 'op su'. but that's fine. Now that I have atleast base setup I can complete that on my own.

Answer (score 2):

This is piggy backing off of Matthew Watson's work.

This version should keep the cursor wherever it was when called, and won't erase the entire row where it started.

It also looks for the last space in the current input and uses everything to the right of that as the "candidate" for lookup:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> commands = new List<string>()
    {
       "add",
       "divide",
       "multiply",
       "subtract",
       "modulus"
    };
    Console.Write("Command: ");
    var cmd = ReadLineWithKeywordExpansion(commands);
    Console.Write("Press Enter to Quit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static string ReadLineWithKeywordExpansion(List<string> commands)
{
    int top = Console.CursorTop;
    int left = Console.CursorLeft;

    var sb = new StringBuilder();           
    while (true)
    {
        var k = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (k.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        else if (k.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
        {
            if (sb.Length > 0)
            {
                --sb.Length;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
                Console.Write(sb.ToString() + " ");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(left + sb.Length, top);
            }
        }
        else if (k.Key == ConsoleKey.Tab)
        {
            int index = 0;
            string candidate = sb.ToString();
            for(int i=(sb.Length-1); i>=0; i--)
            {
                if (sb[i]==' ')
                {
                    index = i+1;
                    candidate = sb.ToString().Substring(index);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (candidate != "")
            {
                string command = commands.FirstOrDefault(cmd => cmd.StartsWith(candidate));
                if (command != null)
                {
                    sb.Length = index;
                    sb.Append(command);
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
                    Console.Write(sb.ToString());
                }
            }                    
        }
        else if (k.KeyChar != '\0') // Ignore special keys.
        {
            sb.Append(k.KeyChar);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
            Console.Write(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with `ReadLine` because that will read until the user presses `ENTER`. Instead you should use only `ReadKey`, something like this:

```
string opName = "";
while(true)
{
    var key = Console.ReadKey();
    if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
       break;

    if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Tab)
    {
        if (opName.StartsWith("op"))
        {
            var opString = opName.Split(" ")[1];
            var opName = "op" + //get operation that starts with opString
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        opName += key.KeyChar;
    }
}

var operationName = var opString = opName.Split(" ")[1];
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I wanted the input to be shown immediately to user so that he can decide if it matches with what he wanted to choose. I can add a form feed to get it done along with your solution.